# Using pytest.fixture to opt out of function

Tags: python, pytest

I have a function that I don't want to run every time I run tests in my Flask-RESTFul API.  This is an example of the setup:

```
class function(Resource):
    def post(self):
        print 'test'
        do_action()
        return {'success':True}
```

in my test I want to run this function, but ignore do_action().  How would I make this happen using pytest?

Comment: Do you want to skip the test entirely on some runs. Or do you want to always have this test run by have it run with `do_action()`  followed by running without it?

Comment: i want it to skip the test entirely.

Comment: what about something like: import pytest
@pytest.fixture(scope="function", autouse=True)

Answer (score 1):

This seems like a good opportunity to [mark](https://pytest.org/latest/example/markers.html) the tests

```
@pytest.mark.foo_test
class function(Resource):
    def post(self):
        print 'test'
        do_action()
        return {'success':True}
```

Then if you call with

```
py.test -v -m foo_test
```

It will run only those tests marked "foo_test"

If you call with

```
py.test -v -m "not foo_test"
```

It will run all tests not marked "foo_test"

Comment: i want to run the test, i just dont' want to do the do_action(), that is interesting though.

Comment: @Rob Do you want to *both* run the test case with `do_action()` and without `do_action()` every time you run the test suite? Or do you want to toggle if `do_action()` is called based on how you invoke the test suite?

Comment: toggle how its invoked.

Comment: This can certainly be done but the question is how much of this code can you change? While it might not be the cleanest you could always use the approach in this answer along with an extra layer of indirection to set up some function calls that pass a parameter to the `function.post` which you then add a conditional check before executing `do_action`.

Answer (score 1):

You can mock `do_action` in your test:

```
def test_post(resource, mocker):
    m = mocker.patch.object(module_with_do_action, 'do_action')
    resource.post()
    assert m.call_count == 1
```

So the actual function will not be called in this test, with the added benefit
that you can check if the `post` implementation is actuall calling the function.

This requires [pytest-mocker](https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest-mock) to
be installed (shameless plug).